# Rails 4.1.4 ActionController param is missing or the value is empty: name

Tags: strong-parameters, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am relatively new to learning how to code and I am really having problems understanding how to write the code for dealing with parameters in a private method in the controller of a Rails 4.1.4 app so that my app works correctly by allowing me to enter a new picture album name, save it to the db, and have it be persisted so that the name of the new album added shows correctly (currently, it does not work right at all). Can someone please help me? Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for my albums controller:

```
        class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
           def index
             @albums = Album.all
           end

           def new
             @album = Album.new
           end

           def create
             @album = Album.new(album_params)
             @album.save
             redirect_to albums_path
           end

           def show
             @album = Album.find(params[:id])
           end

           def edit
           end

           def update
           end

           private

           def album_params
             params.require(:name).permit(:id, :category)
           end
         end
```

Also, here is my album model:

```
          class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :user
            has_many :photos
          end
```

And here is my migration for the albums:

```
          class CreateAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration
            def change
              create_table :albums do |t|
                t.string :name  # Column for album name of type string
                t.string :category # Column for photography category of type string

                t.timestamps
              end
            end
          end
```

Here is my code for my app/views/albums/index.html.erb file:

```
     <div><%= link_to "Admin Access to Add New Album", new_album_path %></div>
       <div><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></div>

     <h1>Albums Gallery</h1>

      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <div><%= link_to album.name, "/albums/#{album.id}" %></div>
      <% end %>
```

Here is my code from my app/views/albums/new.html.erb file where I use the form_for thing:

```
        <h2>New Albums</h2>
        <%= link_to "Back", albums_path %>

        <%= form_for (@album) do |f| %>
          <div>
            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
          </div>
          <%= f.submit "Add Album" %>
        <% end %>
```

Everything up to the form_for part where I try to enter a new picture album name works. It's at this point where everything just unravels and won't work for me. Instead of accepting and then showing the new album by name, it displays "/albums/3" when it should display "Nature Scenes". I went into my rails console to see what was going on on the db level and the new albums are not being created and saved correctly. My output from the Rails console looks like this:

> 2.1.2 :007 > Album.all   Album Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "albums".* FROM "albums"  => #, #, #,
>
> , #
>
> nil, category: nil, created_at: "2014-09-21 02:50:54", updated_at:
>   "2014-09-21 02:50:54">]> 
>   2.1.2 :008 >

(Sorry about the copy/paste,  but being too new at trying to learn how to code, I don't have enough reputation points on Stackoverflow to be allowed to simply post a screenshot yet.)

Comment: Never mind. I finally found the answer to my question after reading the entire Rails 4 Way book. I needed to change the private method param value of :name to :album. It works now. I figured it out on my own and got the app working (at least, as far as I got with the app as I have a long ways to go to complete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, never mind, I got it. I had the wrong value in the private method. I changed it to

```
       def album_params
         params.require(:album).permit(:id,:name, :category)
       end
```

And now the app works fine (at least, so far - I have a long way to go to complete it).